# Toggle SVG With Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, svg, toggle

Hello there Stack Overflow community, I am a graphic designer trying to get my head around code. I am dealing with SVG Graphics that I need to toggle between. In the page I would like to have them ontop of each other and depending which button is pressed is the one the user sees. Here is the code and I will provide a workflow to give some extra perspective. I apologize in advance if the code is hideous.

[Visual Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZkMI.jpg)

```js
function showGroup(group)
{
    $("#hideables").children('div.'+group).show();
    $("#hideables").children('div').not('.'+group).hide();
}
```

```html
<div class="catProdAttributeItem"><input type="radio" id="34656268" name="5905984" mandatory="1" onclick="showGroup('Solid')"/><span>Solid </span></div>
                              <div class="catProdAttributeItem"><input type="radio" id="34656273" name="5905984" mandatory="1" onclick="showGroup('Split')"/><span>Split $10</span></div>
                              <div class="catProdAttributeItem"><input type="radio" id="34657110" name="5905984" mandatory="1" onclick="showGroup('Marble')"/><span>Marble $15</span></div>
                              <div class="catProdAttributeItem"><input type="radio" id="34657110" name="5905984" mandatory="1" onclick="showGroup('Split Marble')"/><span>Split Marble $15</span></div>
                           </div>
                           
<div id="hideables">                          
<svg id="Solid" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="609.1" height="609.1" viewBox="0 0 609.1 609.1">
  <title>Avian-Solid</title>
  
  <div class="Solid">
  <rect width="610" height="610" style="fill: blue";  class="basecolor"/>
  
  </div>
</svg>

<svg id="Solid" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="609.1" height="609.1" viewBox="0 0 609.1 609.1">
  <title>Split</title>
  <div class="SplitSVG">
  <rect width="610" height="610" style="fill: green";  class="basecolor"/>
  </div>
</svg>

<svg id="Solid" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="609.1" height="609.1" viewBox="0 0 609.1 609.1">
  <title>Marble</title>
  <div class="MarbleSVG">
  <rect width="610" height="610" style="fill: red";  class="basecolor"/>
  </div>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off. One big mistake you made was having `<div>` elements inside your SVGs.  `<div>` is not a valid SVG element.

Anyway, here's how I would do it.

On click, we pass to `showGroup()` an array of the SVG `id`s we want to show.  In `showGroup()` we first hide all SVGs, then turn back on all the ones with the ids that have been passed in.

```js
function showGroup(groups)
{
    // Hide all SVGs
    $("#hideables svg").hide();

    // Now show just the ones we want
    $.each(groups, function(i, item) {
      $('#'+item).show();
    });
}


// Initialise the page by hiding all SVGs.
// (The empty array parameter results in none being shown)
showGroup([]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="catProdAttributeItem"><input type="radio" id="34656268" name="5905984" mandatory="1" onclick="showGroup(['Solid'])"/><span>Solid </span></div>
                              <div class="catProdAttributeItem"><input type="radio" id="34656273" name="5905984" mandatory="1" onclick="showGroup(['Split'])"/><span>Split $10</span></div>
                              <div class="catProdAttributeItem"><input type="radio" id="34657110" name="5905984" mandatory="1" onclick="showGroup(['Marble'])"/><span>Marble $15</span></div>
                              <div class="catProdAttributeItem"><input type="radio" id="34657110" name="5905984" mandatory="1" onclick="showGroup(['Split','Marble'])"/><span>Split Marble $15</span></div>
                           </div>
                           
<div id="hideables">                          
<svg id="Solid" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="609.1" height="609.1" viewBox="0 0 609.1 609.1">
  <title>Avian-Solid</title>
  <rect width="610" height="610" style="fill: blue";  class="basecolor"/>
</svg>

<svg id="Split" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="609.1" height="609.1" viewBox="0 0 609.1 609.1">
  <title>Split</title>
  <rect width="610" height="610" style="fill: green";  class="basecolor"/>
</svg>

<svg id="Marble" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="609.1" height="609.1" viewBox="0 0 609.1 609.1">
  <title>Marble</title>
  <rect width="610" height="610" style="fill: red";  class="basecolor"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly and did exactly what I needed.